# EntityFramework in .NET - when adding child entity to existing parent, parent is being validated/added

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework with .NET and I have, among others, entities Invoice (parent) and receipt (child). They are modeled as shown below:

```
public class Invoice
{       
  public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field Date is mandatory for the invoice.")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
}

public class Receipt
{     
  public int ReceiptID { get; set; }
...
  public int? InvoiceID { get; set; }    
  public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

I have the invoice added in the database already. The problem is when I try to add a receipt for it. In order to do this, I use a FormView, with properties ItemType="Models.Receipt", ValidateRequestMode="Enabled", InsertMethod="AddReceipt":

```
public void AddReceipt(Models.Receipt receiptObj)
{
  receiptObj.InvoiceID = intInvoiceID; //from POST
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var _db = new Models.InvoiceContext();
       _db.Receipts.Add(receiptObj);
       _db.Entry(receiptObj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
      _db.SaveChanges();            
    }
 }
```

The ModelState.IsValid returns false. The error message is "Field Date is mandatory for the invoice." - But I am not trying to add an invoice! When I inspect the "ModelState" in Debug, in ModelState.Keys I see values "Invoice.InvoiceNumber" and "Invoice.InvoiceDate"...?

If I try to load the invoice

```
receiptObj.Invoice= GetInvoice(intInvoiceID);
```

I still get the same validation error, even if when I inspect in Debug the invoice.Bill, I see that it is loaded properly- including the date field. (But fetching the invoice this way is not ok because I'll receive another error when I solve the validation problem because I use a different context when I call GetInvoice(intInvoiceID) and I can't attach the invoice object to two different contexts.)

I'm stuck with this for some time, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to declare your `Invoice` as virtual on `Receipt` class?

Comment: This change doesn't seem to have any impact, but thank you.

Comment: Did you create a new migration and apply it after set the Invoice as virtual ?

Comment: I think you're asking me if the database has changed according to the changes made to the model? Yes, I've removed the database and reinitialized it after declaring the Invoice of the Receipt "virtual".

Comment: ok, did you change the context configuration such as removing lazy loading ?

Comment: No, this is my Context: public class InvoiceContext : DbContext
    {
        public InvoiceContext() : base("billIt2")
        {
        }      

        public DbSet<Bill> Invoices { get; set; }
        ...public DbSet<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }

Comment: ok, last thing I am thinking is the way that you use your context, try to do it with a using clause.

Comment: Ok. I will do that and get back on the results. Thank you!

Comment: As a sidenote: Having `[Required(...)]` on a non-nullable `DateTime` looks strange to me. How is this ever firing under any circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! I'm posting it in case someone else encounters it.

Inside the FormView which I use to insert/upate the receipt, I had a label which displayed the invoice number.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceNumber_edit" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice.InvoiceNumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Because of the Bind, each time I was trying to insert/update a receipt, the context was also trying to insert a new invoice - but since for this new invoice only the InvoiceNumber field was bound, all the other fields were null - this is why the validation for the mandatory field Date of the invoice failed.

Thank you all for your interest and suggestions.